# use animation-mixer for playing glb file, why not start from the beginning? It always start from the middle of the animation where I am using nft

Tags: aframe

Below is the code I use:
I use glb file and it should start animation from the beginning when marker is activated, but It start from the middle of the animation.

```
<div class="arjs-loader">
    <div>Loading, please wait...</div>
</div>

<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"
         renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;"
         embedded arjs="trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;">

    <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="dja" src="./arfile2.glb"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>

    <a-nft type='nft' url='./demo/marker/djarum'
           smooth='true' smoothCount='10' smoothTolerance='0.01' smoothThreshold='5'>

        <a-entity gltf-model='#dja'
                  scale="90 90 90"
                  position="100 -200 0"
                  rotation="-90 0 0"
                  animation-mixer >
        </a-entity>
    </a-nft>

    <a-entity camera>
    </a-entity>
</a-scene>

<!--<a-scene>
    <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="tree" src="./tesla/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>

    <a-entity gltf-model="#tree" scale="0.6 0.6 0.6" position="0 0.15 -3"></a-entity>
</a-scene>-->
```

Answer (score 1):

The `animation-mixer` starts the animation when the model is loaded, not when it's visible.

You can wait until the image [is detected](https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/ui-events/), and then attach the `animation-mixer`:

```
const model = document.querySelector("[gltf]")
const nft = document.querySelector("a-nft");
nft.addEventListener("markerFound", () => {
   model.setAttribute("animation-mixer", "")
})
```